# Where is the Ancient Device for "Wheel of Misfortune"?

Tags: diablo-iii

What is the Ancient Device? Where can it be found and how it is used in the Desolate Sands (Act 2)? Can it be used multiple times? (How else can I experience its possibilities?)

[image: Ancient Device achievement]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Ancient Device is a random event. It takes up a large area of the Desolate Sands, as per the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

Of the possibilities thrown up by the device, some are dungeons (like The Veiled Treasure), and some will likely be other affects.

Possibilities (so far):

1. The Veiled Treasure (dungeon)
2. Appearance of several Vile Swarm (monster)
3. Diseased Bodies (monster)
4. The Fowl Lair (dungeon)
5. Resplendent Chest
6. A boss minion with several skeleton (monster)
7. Many piles of gold
8. Ancient urn
9. Chest (normal)
   10.Eranutet (purple named monster)

Comment: I will add to the list at the end as I come across them. Others should feel free to add to it as well

Comment: The list can be seen at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71381/wheel-of-misfortune

where the a small farming guide is available aswell.

Answer (score 4):

I just randomly found this today on a plateau like area in the middle of the Desolate Sands. You can use it once then you need to find it again after reloading the level.