# How to use the 'Ancient Device' in the Desolate Sands?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have found the 'Ancient Device' spawn in the Desolate Sands area, and talked to the guy who was afraid to use it.  He ran off, and I searched his brother's body and bag and found some gold and a journal.  How do I use the device though?  I might have clicked on the pedestal on accident, because some floating orb or something appeared to be there.  After that I couldn't do anything with it.  I left the plateau for a second, and came back and the orb appeared to be gone and I still couldn't use the device.  It seems like I ought to be able to use it to teleport somewhere.  Am I missing something?  Or do I just need to reload and try again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the Ancient Device for "Wheel of Misfortune"?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69452/where-is-the-ancient-device-for-wheel-of-misfortune)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ancient Device gives you a random result each time you find it within the Desolate Sands (after reloading level), there is an achievement called "wheel of Fortune" for getting each outcome. I have only found it once while playing and it gave me a couple dozen piles of gold.

Comment: I can confirm this, I farmed the Desolate Sands for a loooooooong time before finally getting the achievement. Keep in mind that only two of the ten possible outcomes are dungeons (The Veiled Treasure and The Fowl Lair)

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I thought it was always a dungeon.  I must have gotten a result and not known it.  It just looked like a waypoint or portal to me.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have gotten these outcomes
1.) Skeletons(with a unique namer)
2.) Vile swarms
3.) a useless ancient urn
4.) The Fowl Lair
5.) Veiled Treasure vault
6.) a regular chest
7.) a respelendent chest
8.) piles of spewing gold
9.) a pile of diseased bodies
10.)2 purple namers will spawn, look like golems

Answer (score 0):

I have found it 6 times now after about 100 attempts...3 time got credit and 3 strikeouts not even credit for the achievement... and 3 times near the ancient path other 3 in the north section.

Comment: Hey, Gary, welcome to Arqade!  This answer should be for [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69452/where-is-the-ancient-device-for-wheel-of-misfortune) question, as that asks where to find it, not this one.