# Wheel of Misfortune

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

What are the 10 possibilities for Wheel of Misfortune?

And what is the best way to farm them?

Comment: heh. golden showers. heh. Blizzard's sense of humor is disturbing at times.

Comment: Truely. The wierd thing was that I didnt think about it before I wrote the post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The ten possible combinations are:

**Mobs:**

1. Vile Swarms
2. Diseased Bodies
3. Malice the Mangler (yellow mob)
4. Ernutet (purple mob)
5. Zorr the Doomed (can't remember his color)

**Dungeons:**

1. The Veiled Treasure (Dungeon)
2. The Fowl Lair (Dungeon)

**Containers:**

1. Ancient Urn
2. Resplendent Chest

**Misc:**

1. Gold Shower

How to farm them: [image: How to farm them]

Here you can see the route (blue) and the two possible spawn positions. In the bottom left where the route starts is where you will spawn (the checkpoint thingy).

The answer's from [here](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/wheel-of-misfortune).

Hope this helps. I've tried it a few times, but I'm too lazy to continue.

Comment: What I ended up doing was:
1. Getting the Checkpoint at the edge of the Desolate Sands.
2. Running up to the first point.
3. Exploring first point. 
4. Exit and repeat. 

I didnt see a reason to run to the second spawning location as it would take some time with all the mobs and everything. But beware that the exploding kemikaze mobs can start at the top of you own spawning point.

Comment: I've encountered another gold mob not listed on here. He was a skeleton, and while I forget his full name, the suffix was "The Darkness" or something similar. [This video](http://youtu.be/u99sOj1GOmg) lists a regular chest as a possible outcome, and shows yet another gold skeleton mob, "Grapewound Torment". Thus there are several gold skeleton mobs that all count as one possibility for the purposes of this achievement, and that a regular chest is the tenth, separate outcome. I saw the achievement tick up one when I first encountered him as well as when I first saw the skeletons.

Comment: @knives Like all rare monsters in this game, the rare monster that can be spawned by the Ancient Device has a random name and attributes. The possibility (one of the 10) is "Rare skeleton spawns", not "rare skeleton with this name and these attributes spawns". Purple-named monsters like Ernutet are unique, not rare, and always have the same name and attributes (I think Ernutet is an Illusionist).

Comment: What is the best quest to start to be closest to this map?

Comment: Here are the two locations drawn of the same map (copy/paste) with gimp. Just to make clear that you can't miss them. [Wheel of Fortune locations](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hJMcJ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to farm this is to set your quest to "The Black Soulstone" and go into the archives to get the checkpoint. Then, here and on every subsequent attempt, run out, and check the top spawn point; failing that, TP and warp to "The Ancient Path." Run to the lower spawn point; if it doesn't spawn, TP and quit.

If the area has several large bone heads, tar pits, or a completely flat LARGE area with bones on the ground, leave immediately as the Ancient Device (or any other events) won't spawn there.

Either spawn point can also have either a large circle where dervishes spawn or a spiral path inside a large spine. These may be worthwhile for you to do as both have resplendent chests, which have a very high chance of dropping gems. For the first, kill all the dervishes to open the chest. For the second, open the chest, kill the 3 skeletons that spawn, then TP to avoid the rest of the monsters.

Both of these events can spawn at the same time, and one can spawn at one point and the Ancient Device may still spawn at the other.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've dealt with, with HOURS of trying this challenge...

- There's the Foul Lair - with chickens & a pig, full of treasure
- The Veiled Treasure dungeon full of chests
- Vile Swarms
- Shower of Gold
- Ancient Urn
- Resplendent Chest
- A Yellow Mob (mine were the big golem like things)
- A Purple Mob (again, mine were the big golem things)

Still waiting on the diseased bodies, and the final one, whatever that is... A mob of skeletons?

---

**EDIT**:
A few minutes after posting, I actually had the ancient artifact spawn (probably) about 8 out of 10 attempts... Unfortunately, only 1 of them was one of the 3 I needed.

So it's as above, however, there is a resplendant chest, a standard chest, an urn, gold, the vile swarms, the golem-like monster things, the 2 vaults (veiled treasure and fowl lair) and I assume the final 2 are the skeletons and diseased bodies...

If only I got those 2 instead of the swarms - seem to get those almost every time now...