# Easter egg in act 2(desolate sands)

Tags: diablo-iii

How do you get the portal in act 2 in the center of the desolate sands to work? If you press the stone to the left of it it does nothing... What do you do to get it to actually do something?

Answer (score 1):

It's part of an achievements. Pressing the stone has 10 different outcome and you must get each one to unlock "[Wheel of Misfortune](http://www.d3achieve.com/campaign/act2/wheel-of-misfortune)"

Comment: There are ten different outcomes. Only [two of them](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71381/wheel-of-misfortune) are dungeons.

Comment: @JC2k8 i was hesitating between 8 and 10, my memroy failed me ><